# SSH list directories?

Tags: ssh

I just started with SSH 10 minutes ago. I enter:

```
ssh lisv22@chusmix.com
my password
```

And get:

```
Last login: Fri Sep  9 20:31:29 2011 from 190.220.54.6
-bash-3.2$
```

Which I suppose means I connected successfully. However when trying to access any directory on my root I get an error.

E.G:

```
/game
```

returns `/game: No such file or directory.` Btw I also tried `/html/game`

What am I doing wrong? / how do I get a list of directories?

Comment: FYI, the domain you mention has an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: out of interest, how did you find that out?

Comment: You're not new to SSH. You're new to *nix my friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just typing the name of the directory? That will make `bash` try to execute it as if it was a command.

Use `cd` to navigate directories and `ls` to list files in that directory:

```
cd /game          # sets the working directory to /game
ls                # lists all files in /game (since the default is the working directory)
ls /html/game     # lists all files in /html/game
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ssh lisv22@chusmix.com 'ls'` to view directory listing.